# ggplot boxplot - cannot get my plot to work, no 'box' plotted

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am following an example here: [ggplot2 - Multiple Boxplots from Sources of Different Lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918358/ggplot2-multiple-boxplots-from-sources-of-different-lengths) and trying to adapt it to my data. You can access my data here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1A4P6vaHgqrmeakCGR-zMYZQvyDgZLrzw?usp=sharing

My code:

```
JD <- data.frame(group="JD",value=scan("......../abs_len_jd.csv", what="", sep="\n"))
LI <- data.frame(group="LI",value=scan("........./abs_len_li.csv", what="", sep="\n"))
JAS <- data.frame(group="JAS",value=scan("....../abs_len_jas.csv", what="", sep="\n"))

# Combine into one long data frame
plot.data <- rbind(JD, LI, JAS)

# Plot
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

The resulting plot does not look like box plot at all:

[image]

What have I done wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. You would need a `group` var. If I am correct, it should be your group according to the file and then having one box per class:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Combine into one long data frame
plot.data <- rbind(JD, LI, JAS)
plot.data$value <- as.numeric(plot.data$value)
# Plot
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=group,group=group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes it creates exactly this plot. Can I ask how to fix the y-axis? I am trying "+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500))" but it gives an error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". I guess the 'scan' function loads the data values as labels, not numbers. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Ziqi Just give a moment to update the post!

Comment: @Ziqi I have updated the code for you. Issue was due to a character variable. Improved. Hope that helps and let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thanks, that's great!

Comment: @Ziqi Nice, a pleasure helping you :) kind regards!